# detecting touch on a button inside a scroll view in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a table view with custom cells.Inside the cell having a scroll view which scrolls horizontally.A button is added on the the table view cell.But the button is not responding with touch.Button is not added on the scroll view.On this button click,my task is to change the offset of the scroll view behind it just as a next button.How can i detect the touch?This is my code of adding contents to scroll view.

```
 for(int i=0;i<[exerciseArrayForeachSection count];i++){

        Exercise *data = [exerciseArrayForeachSection objectAtIndex:i];

        [_customCell.exTitleLabel setText:data.exName];
         if([data.exImage length] < 1){
             [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingURL:_customCell.exThumbImageView.imageURL];
         }
      else  if ([data.exImage length] > 0)
        {
            int intExerId = [data.exImage intValue];
            NSString *fullPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d/%@",EXER_URL,intExerId,data.exImage];
            NSURL* aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullPathString];


            _customCell.exThumbImageView.imageURL = aURL;
            imageUrlDetails=fullPathString;
        }

     [_customCell.scroll addSubview:_customCell.excerciseDetailsView];


         _customCell.scroll.contentOffset=CGPointMake(_customCell.scroll.contentOffset.x+320, _customCell.scroll.contentOffset.y);

        }

    [_customCell addSubview:_customCell.scroll];
     [_customCell.scroll bringSubviewToFront:_customCell.nextBtn];


        }
```

Method for the button click is called from the custom cell view like:

```
-(IBAction)nextClickActn:(id)sender{
   [[self delegate]nextButtonAction:self];}
```

And in table view controller,

```
- (void)  nextButtonAction:(id)sender {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender;
    _customCell=(CustomCellFor_Dashboard*)cell;


   if ( _customCell.scroll.contentOffset.x <= _customCell.scroll.contentSize.width ) {
       CGRect frame;
       frame.origin.x = _customCell.scroll.contentOffset.x +_customCell.scroll.frame.size.width;
       frame.origin.y = 0;
       frame.size = _customCell.scroll.frame.size;
       [_customCell.scroll scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
      // pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
   }

}
```

Comment: have you add target method in you button?

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya have edited the question.target method is calling from the tableview cell class and that method is given above

Comment: [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextButtonAction
:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: the thing is nextButtonAction is called as delegate method from snother view.

Comment: ok then set if condition when its call from uitableview cell or not.
Use 1 bool variable.

Comment: @keyurbhalodiya thans for ur help.Ticked ans below solved it..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,
Implement this into cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
UIButton *accessoryView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(190, 5, 40, 41)];

accessoryView.tag = indexPath.row;
             [accessoryView addTarget: self action:@selector(yourMethodWhichUWantToCall:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
             cell.accessoryView = accessoryView;
```

And after that implement the following code in that method:

```
UIButton *accessoryView = (UIButton *)sender;

UITableViewCell *cell;

if(isIOS7)
{
   cell = (UITableViewCell *)accessoryView.superview.superview;
}
else
{
   cell = (UITableViewCell *)accessoryView.superview;
}
```

Comment: but its not calling even this method -(IBAction)nextClickActn:(id)sender; on the click

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use this line

```
self.button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

or you can use.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];

// prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;    

[pageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Comment: button interaction is already enabled,and before adding the scroll view the touch is detecting fine.

Comment: button.clipToBounds = YES - try this